# Ruby Array Mysteriously Fails?

Tags: ruby, arrays

This fails

```
require 'rinruby'
r = RinRuby.new(:echo => false)
spreads = []
spreads << 44
spreads << 2
r.assign "test", spreads

/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:656:in `rescue in assign_engine': Unsupported data type on Ruby's end (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:635:in `assign_engine'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:405:in `assign'
```

This works

```
require 'rinruby'
r = RinRuby.new(:echo => false)
r.assign "test", [44, 2]
```

What is going on?? If I print out spreads.class and [44, 2].class they both give an array.

Comment: Does `spreads == [44, 2]` return `true`?

Comment: Your demonstration would be more convincing if you used `=` instead of `||=`. The natural question readers would ask is "Was `spreads` set to something else?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to sawa and Matt for the comments above.  It helped me realize what the problem was.  The above example was simplified to be easier to read on here, but it contained the assumption that my true data in my array wasn't causing a problem.  When I did the test you gave me sawa, I found that it worked, so I saw the problem must be my data.  Then I saw that even though my data looked identical to the sample array's above, it had numbers in BigDecimal format, which rinruby was rejecting.  When I changed those to floats, it worked.

Comment: I won't.  It says I can't accept for another 2 days.